# How to set syntax enable permanently in Vim

Tags: mac, terminal, vim, syntax-highlighting, syntax

How do I make Vim to remember the `syntax enable` (or `syntax on`) command, so I don't have to type it every time I open a new file?

Comment: I can recommend http://vi.stackexchange.com/ for Vim related questions.

Answer (score 2):

Put your stuff in `~/.vimrc`. Search for a good script for developing `c`, you can find good indentation and other options.

Answer (score 1):

Create .vim folder in your home directory (if not exist) and ftplugin

```
mkdir ~/.vim
mkdir ~/.vim/ftplugin
vi  ~/.vim/ftplugin/c.vim
```

now start type your commands for example :

```
!echo 'I am c file ,, '
```

now save :w